# How To Shape Orientation of Ipad-like Popover?

Tags: swift, cell, popover, collectionview

I have 2 questions.

1) Currently, my `iPad` `popover` is working but the arrow is pointing downward on top of button. How do I flip it so the arrow points upward and the `ViewController` is under the button?

2) how do I keep the layout the same if I turn my phone (it will become full screen).

Below is my code for the `popover` that has emojis.

```
@IBAction func emojiButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmojiController") as! EmojiViewController
    VC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

    let popOver = navController.popoverPresentationController
    popOver?.sourceView = sender
    popOver?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    popOver?.delegate = self

    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question: You can use the [`permittedArrowDirections`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622319-permittedarrowdirections) property of the `UIPopoverPresentationController` to give a hint which arrows you allow. In your case, use `UIPopoverArrowDirection.up`

The second question I do not quite understand - what do you mean with

> how do I keep the layout the same if I turn my phone

What layout?

Comment: I mean when I flip the phone horizontally, the cell sizes change and the view controller changes from 200 by 100 to full size.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. You don't want to resize the view? Maybe a screenshot would be helpful to show what you want / not want.